# rspec gives error Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure

Tags: rspec, mongoid, moped

When i run tests rspec, i get error

```
1) Nimba::Storages DropboxStorages returns http success
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure:
   Could not connect to a primary node for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

I don't no why this occure this error?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding a row to spec/spec_helper.rb

```
DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
```